# div position in IE8 doesn't work without setting "width"

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, position

I would like to have the following layout with div:

```
+----------------------+---------------+
|                      |               |
|                      |               |
|                      |   rightDiv    |
|                      |               |
+**********************+***************+
|             bottomDIV|               |
+**************************************+
```

2 DIVs (rightDiv and bottomDiv) into a DIV container (containerDiv). The first one is floating on the right and the second one is standing on the bottom. The containerDiv height cannot be fixed: it should have the same height of the rightDiv div, that can change when data inside change.

I wrote the code:

```
<div id="ContainerDiv" style="position:relative; border: 1px black solid;width:300px">
    <div id="rightDiv" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; float:right;">
        XXXXXXXX<br/>
        XXXXXXXX<br/>
        XXXXXXXX<br/>
        XXXXXXXX<br/>
    </div>


    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div id="BottomDiv" style="border: 1px solid blue; position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:100%; text-align:center; ">
        BOTTOM
    </div>
</div>
```

If I remove the "width:300px" property in the containerDiv, in Chrome I still having the same result, but in IE8 the "BottomDiv" goes out the "containerDiv" and stands in the bottom of the page, far from the rest of the composition.
Why do I need to put the width value?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Define "doesn't work", please.

Comment: I added new details in the text. The problem is about the bottomDiv that in IE8 goes outside the containerDiv, standing on the bottom of the page. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work in ie8 if you set "margin:auto"?  or "width:auto"? or "width:100%"?

Comment: with "margin:auto" and "width:auto", it doesn't work. With "width:100%", it works.
On IE8, it seems I need to specify the width, but why? Is it my sintax correct? Who is not respecting the "standards": IE8 or Chrome? Thank you